# LLDB: how to make a custom function that pretty prints a dynamic array of structs

Tags: c, xcode, struct, printing, lldb

I have an dynamically allocated array of structs that I need to print inside LLDB, while in a breakpoint. All this happening in some pure C code outside ObjC.

I've written a static function that does the printing job and while I can call it inside LLDB, it will only print about 60 lines before silently stopping. Sometimes, it will not print anything unless I press Enter again inside LLDB. I assume this is due to threading somehow, but I tried to do a dispatch_async inside that function without any success - it wouldn't print anything.

Therefore, I am looking into alternative solutions (maybe a Python script) to get a pretty print of that array as it is vital for my debugging efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about something like:

```
struct MyStruct {/* some stuff */};
struct MyStruct *struct_ptr = malloc(100 * sizeof(struct MyStruct));
```

and you want to print struct_ptr as if you had done:

```
struct MyStruct struct_arr[100];
```

If you are on lldb before Xcode 8.0, you would do this with:

(lldb) memory read -c 100 -t MyStruct struct_ptr

And if you have one of the Xcode 8.0 beta's, you can use the new parray command:

(lldb) parray 100 struct_ptr

Comment: I was hoping to get more control over the printed output, but this works magnificently!  One thing worth mentioning is that for bigger arrays (or better yet bigger structs), one would need to `set set target.max-memory-read-size 1048576` - or some value big enough to hold your data.

Comment: parray is just an alias for `expression -Z <Count>   -- <Expression>` so if you want to use other formatting options, just spell the command out fully and you can add any of the formatting options the "expression" command offers.  See `help expression`, and remember you have to put the options before the `--`.